# The following inequality is it correct?

Tags: number-theory, inequality

let $0<\alpha_1\leq\dots\leq\alpha_m$ and $0<\beta_1\leq\dots\leq\beta_m\leq\frac{1}{m-1}$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\beta_i=1.$$
Is the following inequality correct
$$\big(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\big)\big(\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\beta_i}{\alpha_i}\big)\leq m$$

Comment: Do you mean $\big(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\big)\big(\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\beta_i}{\alpha_i}\big)\ge m-1$?

Comment: yeah $\big(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\big)\big(\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\beta_i}{\alpha_i}\big)\geq m$

Comment: Check $m=2$, $\alpha_1 =  \frac{1}{100}, \alpha_2 = 1$, $\beta_1 = \frac{1}{10000}, \beta_2 = 1-\beta_1$.

Comment: @RiverLi thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter Example: $\beta_1=\beta_2=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha_1=1,\alpha_2=2$ so

\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+2) \left( \frac{1/2}{1}+\frac{1/2}{2} \right) =\frac{9}{4}
\end{eqnarray*}
which is not less than $2$.

CS would be
\begin{eqnarray*}
\big(\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\big)\big(\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\beta_i^{\color{red}{2}}}{\alpha_i}\big)\geq 1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Beat me to it. In fact if we pick all $\beta_j$s equal to $\frac{1}{m}$, then the opposite result follows for any choice of $\alpha_j$s by Cauchy-Shwarz inequality

Comment: @highgardener Would we need a power of $2$ on the $\beta$'s for CS ?

Comment: My comment will only work for all $\beta_j$s equal. For the general case, what you've added is correct except RHS should be $1$?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit thanks for your answer but i make a big mistake the sign in the inequality is $\geq$  not $\leq$. anyway i solved the problem where i needed this inequality